# Case sum in snowflake and name accordingly

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have joined multiple views to get the following output for time taken by each Department to complete a task. The output looks like this:

| ID | PROCESS | DEPT | SECONDS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S911 | BATCH | SALES | 24268 |
| S911 | BATCH | MKTG | 2992 |
| S911 | BATCH | HR | 77 |
| S911 | BATCH | FIN | 14995 |
| S911 | BATCH | DATA | 739 |
| S911 | BATCH | ITA | 8988 |

I need the output to be this:

| ID | PROCESS | DEPT_2 | SECONDS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S911 | BATCH | EXEMPT | 24345 |
| S911 | BATCH | NONEXEMPT | 24722 |
| S911 | BATCH | OTHERS | 2992 |

Can this possibly done with a case statement where exempt is sum of sales and HR non exempt is sum of finance data and product and of there are any other departments they need to be summed up as others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use a case *expression* in combination with an aggregation.

I don't use Snowflake but I *believe* you can use a column alias in a group-by clause, which would look as follows, where `t` is a derived table or common table expression for your existing query:

```
select Id, Process,
  case 
    when dept in ('SALES', 'HR') then 'EXEMPT'
    when dept in ('FIN', 'DATA', 'ITA') then 'NONEXEMPT'
    else 'OTHERS'
  end Dept_2,
  Sum(Seconds) Seconds
from t
group by Id, Process, Dept_2
order by Dept_2;
```

Comment: Yes, you can use aliases in group by within Snowflake. Snowflake also supports group by 1,2,3.

Comment: Thanks - yes I just looked up in the documentation and indeed it's supported.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This mostly works but what if there is a scenario where 'SALES' need to be included in both the cases? 
  when dept in ('SALES', 'HR') then 'EXEMPT'
  when dept in ('FIN', 'DATA', 'ITA','SALES') then 'NONEXEMPT' In that case this fails. Is there an alternative solution?